# Georeferenced image not showing in QGis

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, epsg

I am trying to get a Georeferenced image into QGis project, but it does not work.

The georeferenced image has 81 points, and I've set the CRS to EPSG:3035 (the same as the project).
[image: Screenshot from georeferencer]

If the QGis project is empty, this actually produce an imported image, but not in the projection I would expect - even though both the layer AND the project is specified as EPSG:3035:
[image: Image from QGis project]

What I would expect, would be something like this, not with a square/quadratic grid, but with straight longitudinal lines and curved latitudinal lines:
[image: Illustration of expected projection in QGis project window]

- If I load another layer first, i.e. as the last photo, the georeferenced image does not show
- If I load the georeferenced image first, then import another layer, the new layer does not show
- If I change layer properties to another projection, it either stays identical OR disappear.
- I've tried several different projections in the georefererence settings, as well as different transformation types, they all give the same square grid projection in project window.
- I've tried different projections in QGis - it does not matter.

What am I doing wrong?

### SOLVED

I discovered the scale of the image was wrong, I must input the coordinates in the correct form for EPSG:3035. I had to do a lot of coordinate conversion on a web page - but it seems like this solved the problem.

Comment: Great.  Can you accept your own answer so your question displays as solved?

Comment: Your georeferencing coordinates are in 4326 and that is what you should use.

Comment: Yeah, it's way easier to georeference the image using the CRS present on it, in this case DMS/EPSG4326. QGIS will place it correctly in relation to your projects CRS.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the scale of the image was wrong, I must input the coordinates in the correct form for EPSG:3035. I had to do a lot of coordinate conversion on a web page - but it seems like this solved the problem.